# Unable to Create AWS Segamaker, Error: The account-level service limit 'Number of elastic inference accelerators across all notebook instances.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-sagemaker

I'm facing an Error Message 
 "The account-level service limit 'Number of elastic inference accelerators across all notebook instances.' is 0 Accelerators, with current utilization of 0 Accelerators and a request delta of 1 Accelerators. Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit."
[image]

I never used this account, I have 500$ in my account. But I'm unable to create the Juypter NoteBook on Aws SageMaker Instances.

I already visited: [AWS Sagemaker Deploy fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595157/aws-sagemaker-deploy-fails)

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default AWS limits the number of instances you can use, here you have the default [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html). As the error message says, you have to request for a limit increase, you can do it from [here](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=us-east-1&skipRegion=true#/case/create), it will take couple of days from my experience.